# Como imprimir/inserir de uma forma organizada dentro de um arquivo csv uma tupla em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tupla

Alguém saberia dizer como faço para imprimir uma tupla da seguinte forma:

```
  amount_of_commits,author  
  148, Steve Ellis     
  2, Alex Kwiatkowski   
  2, Thomas  
  1, Dan Forbes  
  1, David Parker  
  1, John Barker  
  1, Thomas Hodges  
  1,dependabot[bot]
```

O retorno que estou recebendo é do comando `git shortlog -s -n` cujo código encontra-se abaixo:

```
for token in tokens:
insights = open("repositories_insights/" + token + "_insights.csv", "w")
insights.write("amount_of_commits,author\n")
   
data = subprocess.Popen(["git", "-C", "github_repos/" + token + "/" + token, "shortlog",  "-s", "-n"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
print(str(data))
insights.write(data)
insights.close()
```

Quando imprimo o valor tupla `data` o resultado sai da seguinte forma

```
(b'   148\tSteve Ellis\n     2\tAlex Kwiatkowski\n     2\tThomas\n     1\tDan Forbes\n     1\tDavid Parker\n     1\tJohn Barker\n     1\tThomas Hodges\n     1\tdependabot[bot]\n', None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação de `communicate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) o retorno é uma tupla contendo a saída padrão e a saída de erros. Além disso, quando não está no modo texto, o retorno é um objeto do tipo [*bytes*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) (dá para você ver pelo `b` no início da saída). Além disso, como o comando não deu nenhum erro, o segundo elemento da tupla é `None`.

Sendo assim, você precisa pegar o primeiro elemento da tupla (que é a saída padrão do comando) e transformá-lo em string, usando o método [`decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode).

Além disso, o comando está retornando os campos separados por um TAB (`\t`), então basta usar [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) para substituí-lo por vírgula:

```
data = subprocess.Popen(["git", "-C", "github_repos/" + token + "/" + token, "shortlog",  "-s", "-n"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
insights.write(data[0].decode().replace('\t', ', '))
```

Outra opção é ler o `stdout` do processo linha a linha:

```
import subprocess

# atenção, aqui não chama communicate()
data = subprocess.Popen(["git", "-C", "github_repos/" + token + "/" + token, "shortlog",  "-s", "-n"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for s in data.stdout:
    insights.write(s.decode().replace('\t', ', '))
```

---

Outra opção é setar o argumento `universal_newlines`, assim o retorno serão strings em vez de *bytes*, eliminando a necessidade de chamar `decode`:

```
data = subprocess.Popen(["git", "-C", "github_repos/" + token + "/" + token, "shortlog",  "-s", "-n"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True).communicate()
insights.write(data[0].replace('\t', ', '))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou muito :)